# How can I use a PreviewView inside jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I was trying to use a CameraX `PreviewView` inside of a `Composable` via `AndroidView`, but the preview is stretched and the right half is clipped as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih6lg.jpg).
Nevertheless the view seems to occupy the correct space.
This problem only occurs in portrait mode.
I was able to reproduce the problem on two cell phones and in the emulator so I doubt it is hardware specific.

I have tried different scale types, but that does not seem to affect the stretching.
I would report a bug, but I am not sure whether this is a bug in compose or cameraX.

See the code I use below:

```
package com.example.camerapreview

import android.Manifest
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.registerForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.example.pointergun.ui.theme.PointerGunTheme
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
import androidx.camera.core.Preview

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        setContent {
            PointerGunTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    var isPermissionGranted by remember {
                        mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null)
                    }
                    val launcher =
                        registerForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
                            isPermissionGranted = isGranted
                        }
                    when (isPermissionGranted) {
                        true -> CameraPreview(cameraProviderFuture)
                        false -> Text("permission pls")
                        null -> Button(onClick = { launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) }) {
                            Text(text = "Start!")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun bindPreview(
    cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    previewView: PreviewView,
) {
    val preview: Preview = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(RATIO_16_9)
        .build()

    val cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

    var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
}

@Composable
fun CameraPreview(cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>) {

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            PreviewView(context).apply {
                setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
                scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_START
                post {
                    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
                        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                        bindPreview(
                            cameraProvider,
                            lifecycleOwner,
                            this,
                        )
                    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to set the [implementation mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode) for the PreviewView

```
implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
```

In your case :

```
PreviewView(context).apply {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
    scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_START
    implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
    post {
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindPreview(
                cameraProvider,
                lifecycleOwner,
                this,
            )
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
    }
}
```